# Check for firebase's auth user's role when or after logging in

Tags: javascript, firebase

My firebase app has two different roles: `user` and `admin`. I assign these during the creation, which is done as follows:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

...

const user = await admin.auth().createUser({
    email,
    emailVerified: true,
    password,
    displayName: name,
    disabled: false
  })

await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, { role: 'user' })
```

For creating the admin we obviously do the same, but the last line becomes as follows:

```
await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, { role: 'admin' })
```

These separate roles are use in the firebase rules to keep users from accessing certain collections as well as some cloud functions to prevent them from doing certain operations.

What I would like to do is on my client app to limit access to certain sections by checking the user role.

As it stands, when I authenticate I do not have access to the user role, so I don't know how to limit their access based on their role. Here is my authentication code:

```
// authenticating a user
const handle = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    console.log('Authenticated user', user)

    // do stuff
})
```

The issue here is that at this point the user object given to me by `onAuthStateChanged` doesn't have the role.
From the `providerData` attribute all I have is the following:

```
displayName
email
phoneNumber
photoURL
providerId
uid
```

The question is how can I access the user role on the client app to be able to block certain types of users from accessing restricted parts of the client app?

Comment: if you access an "admin" resources using a user with rule: "user" are your receiving an error?

Comment: Yup. I do currently get the `Missing or insufficient permissions` error, which I am leveraging. But, would like to have access to the role itself, if that is possible of course

Comment: I guess I am not clear on the use case...why don't you return a message to the user that they are accessing a resource that they aren't currently permitted to?

Comment: The first time the user's ID token gets refreshed after you set the custom claim, it should be available in the client. Also see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#access_custom_claims_on_the_client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following snippet:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdTokenResult()
  .then((idTokenResult) => {
     // Confirm the user is an Admin.
     if (!!idTokenResult.claims.admin) {
       // Show admin UI.
       showAdminUI();
     } else {
       // Show regular user UI.
       showRegularUI();
     }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

#### Source:

[Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#access_custom_claims_on_the_client)