# How to render a page if the role is equal to "admin"?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently working on displaying different components that depends on the documents role field. I already mapped the usersList from the firestore.

What do i need is to check if the logged in email and password and the roles are equals to "admin" then i will render the specific component for them.

***This is my firebase collection***

[image: This is my firebase collection]

***the pages who wanted to be rendered is Admin and Guest***

[[image: the pages who wanted to be rendered is Admin and Guest2]

***My useEffect***

[image: my UseEffect]

Comment: What does console.log(users) print?

Comment: I see the data from the documents once. but when i refresh it, it became undefined.

Comment: Try console outside useEffect

Comment: @Harry yep im getting it now, but what i need is to have a login functionality which checks if the logged in userType is equal to admin or guest. then render the specific component for them

Comment: Then you need to create two components admin and guest which i think you probably have it as i can see in the screenshot. Now as you get data in console, using that data just put if-else logic to render admin/guest component. Simple.

Comment: @JohnPaulPineda How are you handling authentication? Are you using a React `Context` (e.g. [`FirebaseAuthUserContext`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68871889/3068190))?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Harry , Then you need to create two components admin and guest which i think you probably have, i can see in the screenshot you have shared. Now as you have to get data in the console, using that data just put if-else logic to render the admin/guest component like below.

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdTokenResult()
  .then((idTokenResult) => {
     // Confirm the user is an Admin.
     if (!!idTokenResult.claims.admin) {
       // Show admin UI.
       showAdminUI();
     } else {
       // Show regular user UI.
       showRegularUI();
     }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

For more information on the above can refer to [stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57561044/check-for-firebases-auth-users-role-when-or-after-logging-in) and [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#access_custom_claims_on_the_client)

Comment: @John Paul Pineda does this answer your question?